# Google Cloud Logging assigns ERROR severity to all Python logging.info calls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

It's the first time I use Google Cloud Platform, so please be understanding!

I've built a scheduled workflow that simply runs a Batch job. The job runs Python code and uses the standard `logging` library for logging. When the job is executed, I can correctly see all the entries in Cloud Logging, but all the entries have severity ERROR although they're all INFO.

[image]

One possible reason I've been thinking about is that I haven't used the `setup_logging` function as described in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python#connecting_the_library_to_python_logging). The thing is, I didn't want to run the Cloud Logging setup when I run the code locally.

The questions I have are:

- why does logging "work" (in the sense that logs end up in Cloud Logging) even if I did not use the `setup_logging` function? What is it's real role?
- why do my INFO entries show up with ERROR severity?
- if I include that snippet and that snippet solves this issue, should I include an if statement in my code that detects if I am running the code locally and skips that Cloud Logging setup step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python), you have to use a setup to send correctly logs to `Cloud Logging`.

This setup allows then to use the `Python` logging standard library.

> Once installed, this library includes logging handlers to connect
> Python's standard logging module to Logging, as well as an API client
> library to access Cloud Logging manually.

```py
# Imports the Cloud Logging client library
import google.cloud.logging

# Instantiates a client
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()

# Retrieves a Cloud Logging handler based on the environment
# you're running in and integrates the handler with the
# Python logging module. By default this captures all logs
# at INFO level and higher
client.setup_logging()
```

Then you can use the `Python` standard library to add logs to `Cloud Logging`.

```py
# Imports Python standard library logging
import logging

# The data to log
text = "Hello, world!"

# Emits the data using the standard logging module
logging.warning(text)
```

> - why does logging "work" (in the sense that logs end up in Cloud Logging) even if I did not use the setup_logging function? What is
>   it's real role?

Without the setup, the log will be added to `Cloud Logging` but not with the correct type and as expected. It's better to use the setup.

> - why do my INFO entries show up with ERROR severity?

The same reason explained above

> - if I include that snippet and that snippet solves this issue, should I include an if statement in my code that detects if I am running the
>   code locally and skips that Cloud Logging setup step?

I think no need to add a `if` statement you run the code locally. In this case, the logs should be printed in the console even if the setup is present.